# Uploading Files with different formats to a URL using Java client

Tags: java

I need to write some code in Java to upload a file(.tz format) to a URL(prqs@vks.com) by using HTTP PUT/POST and SMTP.I have no idea how to do this and my application is not a web based application i have to write a pure java client to do this. I searched the net but could not find a suitable tutorial on how to do this also i found a lot of stuff where in they are uploading file using a HTML form to a server. but that is not what i want.

Can you please let me know how this is to be done. If you can direct me to a tutorial or provide any sample code then it would be very helpful. I am scratching my head on this for a long time now.

Thanks
vikeng21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time from a server side Java Application.

If what your asking for is creating an e-mail with an attached file in .tz format then there are some good resources out there.

I personally used the JavaMail API. It comes with attached JavaDoc and examples. Take a look at the samples in the demo directory within. Hopefully it should help you out.

[Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html)

Comment: Thanks Brad.yes i have to send email to an id with an attachment.For that i think i need to use SMTP. I almost forgot about Java Mail API. Let me check if i can figure out something and hopefully i can get something out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Apache Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) for uploading files.
Have a look at [this example](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload) as well. This might work for you

Comment: Thanks Sujay.If this guides me how to do HTTP PUT/POST from the server side then it would be a great help and good starting point for me.